# how to create a negative buffer distance

Tags: gis, arcgis, qgis

I want to  create a negative buffer distance by adding a inner buffer zone inside the polygons;but when i use qgis to create this buffer with negative value the output layer don't display anything like show you this screenshots:

[image]

[image]

who have any idea to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

QGis is helping you out by pointing out that your layer is in **degrees** which means that the `-0.1` distance you have asked for is in degrees not metres (or any other useful length unit). It's not clear what size your polygon is but if it is smaller than `0.1` degrees (roughly 10km) then there is no buffer to display.

So you need to reproject your layer to a planar projection. See [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/106988/79) for details of how to proceed.

Comment: thanks you, i have a vector layer with a lot of polygons so i cant import data with lat and long distinct for exemple of this polygone it's with size(4m)